# What is the hat of a construction worker called in general?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> **[helmet](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/helmet?q=helmet)**: a type of hard hat that protects the head, worn, for example, by a
>   police officer, a soldier or a person riding a bike or motorbike or
>   playing some sports
>
> Police in riot helmets lined the streets.
>
> A protective helmet should be worn at all times.
>
> Cycle helmets dramatically reduce the risk and severity of head
>   injuries.

Look at the picture

[image]

**What is a common word for the hat of a construction worker?**

**Is it a helmet? or a hard hat?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either: a **safety helmet** or **hard hat**.

[image]